# Do I have to use Full System Mode after adding a new device on gem5？

Tags: gem5

I'm trying to add a ORAM module to gem5, it would modify the address from the CPU to Memory. After reading the introduction about how to add a device named HelloDevice to gem5 in ASPLOS 2008 tutorial, I am still confused that  if I add a new device to gem5, do I have to use Full System Mode to run tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello?

Answer (score 0):

`tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello` is an userland executable, meant to be ran with `se.py`.

I think devices are not visible from `se.py` since it only emulates userland by translating simple instructions, and capturing syscalls, you can't see for example arbitrary hardware registers or physical memory.

Therefore yes, I think you need to use full system emulation with your build.

If you don't know how to use `fs.py`, [give this setup a try](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/72e135d2b290d8bc5cd584b8acac828ae5e71eea#gem5-getting-started).

Comment: Thank you，I will have a try.